# Line break in page based Application

Tags: iphone, ios6, uilabel

In my page based application i want to use line-break in uilabel,I try with the following coding,

```
 @"The farmer and his wife were entranced with joy and danced cheerfully because of their goose lays \n a golden egg",


self.titlestring.frame = CGRectMake(53, 620, 0, 37);
self.titlestringcop.frame = CGRectMake(53, 620, 918, 37);
[self fadein];
[self.titlestring setText:self.dataobject1];
[self.titlestringcop setText:self.dataobject1];
textstring.numberOfLines = 0;
titlestringcop.numberOfLines = 0;
CGSize labelSize = [textstring.text sizeWithFont:textstring.font
                               constrainedToSize:textstring.frame.size
                                   lineBreakMode:textstring.lineBreakMode];
CGSize labelSize1 = [titlestringcop.text sizeWithFont:titlestringcop.font
                                    constrainedToSize:titlestringcop.frame.size
                                        lineBreakMode:titlestringcop.lineBreakMode];
textstring.frame = CGRectMake(
                              textstring.frame.origin.x, textstring.frame.origin.y,
                              textstring.frame.size.width, labelSize.height);
titlestringcop.frame = CGRectMake(
                                  titlestringcop.frame.origin.x,    titlestringcop.frame.origin.y,
                                  titlestringcop.frame.size.width, labelSize1.height);
```

But in doesn't showing any difference?Whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this line add these lines also in code & check:

```
textstring.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

titlestringcop.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```